Multiheritance preferences on python classes does not take proper super()
Good morning everyone. I am creating Mixin classes in a project to simplify the overall logic of a class diagram, for which I am using multiherences. However, the issue of multi-inheritance preferences is not very clear to me, or at least it is not clear to me how to avoid what is happening to me. Here is the simplified example:
class A:
    def foo(self):
        return "AAA"

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        return super().foo() + "BBB"

class C(A):
    def foo(self):
        return "CCC"

    def bar(self):
        return "Other logic"

class D(B, C):
    pass

print(D().foo())

In this code we have 4 classes: A, B, C, D . We can see that both B and C inherit from A, but in the case of B we have to change the logic of the method foo, and in the case of the class C also and adds the method bar. What I intend with class D and the preferences set at the time of inheriting is that it has the bar method (that's why it inherits from C), but the foo method returns "AAABBB" which is the logic of the B method. I am aware that what is happening is that the super() of D is also C and that is why it currently returns "CCCBBB" and that would be solved by setting:
class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        return A.foo() + "BBB"

However, this seems ugly to me since the whole point of relegating logic to super() and not specifying it is to simplify changes, and in reality B should not take into account that there may be a class D with that expected output.
What would be the correct way for that code to output "AAABBB" when calling the D class foo?

That's simply how multiple inheritance with MRO in Python works. If you want to manipulate the order, there's bound to be ugly hard-coding involved somewhere to circumvent the logics as designed.

super is misnamed. B should have no assumptions about what super().foo resolves to, as it is entirely dependent on the runtime type of self. super().foo returns the next method in the MRO of self, not necessarily a parent class's method.

Which is to say, if B.foo is expected to return "AAABBB", then it should use A.foo specifically. If that conflicts with what other subclasses of B should return, you may need to rethink either your class hierarchy or whether subclasses should be defining new methods instead of overriding inherited methods.

I think you just need to swap the order of your classes in your multiple inheritance.
class A:
    def foo(self):
        return "AAA"

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        return super().foo() + "BBB"

class C(A):
    def foo(self):
        return "CCC"

    def bar(self):
        return "Other logic"

class D(C, B):          # C first, then B
    def foo(self):
        return super(C, self).foo()

print(D().foo())
# prints:
AAABBB


This: You don't need to define D.foo explicitly, though. The purpose of reordering the base classes is to make a D more like a C than a B. D().foo will resolve to C.foo, which will execute without invoking super again, leading to the desired result.

Keep in mind, though, the "more-like" relationship is "global"; you can't use the same trick to provide different custom behavior on a per-method basis. (That is, you can't make D more C-like for one method, but more B-like for another.)

Actually, re-reading the question, OP wants B.foo to be called, not C.foo, but with different effect.
